# How java can restrict the scope(?) of reference type variable when it is upcasted

Tags: java, jvm

```
public class Car {

    public Car(){
    } 

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("start");
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("stop");
    }  
}
```

```
public class Truck extends Car{

    public Truck(){
    }

    public void load() {
        System.out.println("load");
    }

    public void unload() {
        System.out.println("unload");
    }
}
```

```
Car sample = new Truck();

sample.load();
sample.unload();
```

it does not work

```
Truck newSample = sample
newSample.load();
newSample.unload();
```

it works well

How it's possible ?

Are `sample` and `newSample` stored differently in memory?

Only thing that I know is when I touch the variable, JVM will check the stack area at first...

Comment: They are different on compile time (where no object exists in memory yet). `sample` is *declared* to be a `Car`, which is the only think Java looks at when deciding which methods it allows you to call on it.

Comment: At its core, both objects are `Truck`s, so no difference here. The reason we do not see the `Truck`-specific method in the 1st case is because we reference it as a `Car`, hence we do not know that it is a `Truck`. As an analogy: imagine the exact type depends on user input, and we only know that it will be a `Car`, hence we can only use it as if it were a car (or downcast it).

Comment: Think of this remote - tv analogy: you have a tv with multiple functions, like browsing tv channels, youtube, netflix. However, your remote can only browse tv channels (you have a Car reference), so you will not have access to youtube and netflix. Getting a new remote would work (having a Truck object reference).